# Java caps memory

Tags: java, eclipse, memory

When I try to initialize a big array:

```
double [][][] test = new double[500][500][500];
```

There comes the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at tests.Test.main(Test.java:6)
```

When I give arguments to java, with too big memory:

```
-Xmx2048m
```

There comes the error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
```

and the text is black.

---

Task manager says

`Physical Memory: 44%`

and from my computer I have these stats:

Windows 7 Ultimate

Processor: Intel(R) 'Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GHz

Installed memory (RAM): 8,00 GB (7,89 GB usable)

System type: 64-bit Operating System

Comment: The amount it says it tried to reserve is `2.097152 GB`, which is larger than `-Xmx2048m`

Comment: but should still be possible shouldn't it?

Comment: How should it still be possible?  Because it isn't possible with `-Xmx2048m`, more space needs to be allocated. Use the suggestion @KarolDowbecki made

Comment: I see the problem, no that's not my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is to install java 64bit. I had installed only 32bit.

edit:
thanks to @greg-449 from my earlier question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807186/memory-capped-at-1-gb?noredirect=1#comment94469858_53807186 which was not accepted by the community. My acception is yours!

Answer (score 8):

A `double` is 8 bytes. Your array is `500 * 1000 * 1000 * 8` which is roughly 3.8 GB.

You need to allocate a bigger heap to accommodate this array, try `-Xmx5g` to allow some additional memory for the rest of your application.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the problem. I updated my post, take a look at it. I also tested my update.